# How do I extract numbers from a mixed string?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm in the script editor and would like to take a string variable that looks something like "Front+3, Rear" or "RRD+6" and extract the # value from it for further calculations. How can you strip this information from a string to manipulate it?

Also, I would like to be able to take strings like "Front+2, Rear+7" and end up with the value 9 (adding the 2 and the 7). How can I boil these strings down to numbers in script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More or less, this is what I came up with. The keys being parseFloat and isNaN.

```
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var currentRow = sheet.getActiveRange().getRowIndex(); 
var firstCol = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(currentRow ,1,1,1);
var bumperDetailsStr = firstCol.getValues().toString();
var bodywork = 0;

for(var i=0; i < bumperDetailsStr.length; i++){
 var indChar = bumperDetailsStr.charAt(i);
 var parChar = parseFloat(indChar);
 if (!isNaN(parChar)){
  bodywork=bodywork+parChar;
 }
}
```